# AMD multi-core programming

Tags: c++, multithreading, multicore, openmp, tbb

I want to start  to write applications(C++) that will utilize the additional cores to execute portions of the code that have a need to perform lots of calculations and whose computations are independent of each other. I have the following processor : x64 Family 15 Model 104 Stepping 2 Authentic AMD ~1900 Mhz running on Windows Vista Home premium 32 bit and Opensuse 11.0 64 bit.

On the Intel platforms , I've used the following APIs Intel TBB, OpenMP. Do they work on AMD and does AMD have similar APIs.what has been your experience?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenMP and TBB are both available also for AMD - it is also a compiler question.
E.g. see [linux TBB on AMD](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/08/02/threading-building-blocks-amd-athlon-64-x2-and-gentoo-linux/).
I think the latest development on this end is to use the graphic card via CUDA or similar APIs- but this depends on the nature of your calculations. If it fits, it is faster than the CPU anyway.

Comment: CUDA is very specific business indeed, since the GPU are optimized for 1 operation applied to several 'datum' at once.

Comment: My laptop has a Nvidia card (6150 Go)... how can i get started ?

Comment: Is there any link where someone has tried TBB on a AMD and discussed instrumentation results or given some performance benchmarks?

Is there a AMD equivalent of the TBB library at developer.amd.com ?

Comment: (shameless plug for my own technology) - Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 released last week, so please be sure check out the Parallel Pattern Library and Asynchronous Agents Library which run great on x64 intel & amd.