# Intel TBB will work on AMD processors?

Tags: c++, c, intel, multithreading, tbb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AMD multi-core programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623975/amd-multi-core-programming)

Is [Intel TBB](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) processor dependent? Will it work on amd or on ARM (under meeGo for example?)

Comment: See the statement of intent to support all processors in the FAQ [here](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/wiki/index.php?title=General_Questions_about_TBB#What_compilers.2C_operating_systems_and_processors_are_supported.3F)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is yes, for AMD anyhow.

For ARM things are more complex, judging by feedback on the Intel forums.  I don't see anybody has gotten this working?  For example see http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=74346

The commercial version 3.0 has this in its release notes regarding recommended hardware: other platforms may be more sketchily supported, I would think.

```
Microsoft* Windows* Systems
    Intel(R) Core(TM) 2 Duo processor or Intel(R) Xeon(R) processor
        or higher
Linux* Systems
    Intel(R) Core(TM) 2 Duo processor or Intel(R) Xeon(R) processor
        or Intel(R) Itanium(R) processor or higher
Mac OS* X Systems
    Intel(R) Core(TM) 2 Duo processor or higher
```

(Updated info Dec 2014)
[ARM is supported on TBB as of 4.1 Update 3, with fixes in 4.2 Update 3.](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/495003) I have not used this myself so cannot attest to the robustness of this port.

Comment: Given AMD's recent foray into ARM64, you might want to revise your answer to be specific about AMD x86.

Answer (score 19):

TBB is not completely processor-independent; there is a (rather small) layer that isolates the rest of TBB from processor architecture (primarily to provide atomic read-modify-write operations such as compare-and-swap) and certain OS pecularities. Implementations of this layer use some compiler-specific stuff as well, such as inlined assembler or built-in functions (intrinsics).

TBB will work out-of-the-box on x86 (32 and 64 bit) processors including those from AMD, except for rather old ones that do not have `mfence` instruction.

As for ARM, there is no direct support, but [TBB 3.0 Update 7](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/ver.php?fid=171) added an implementation of TBB's platform isolation layer that uses GCC atomic built-ins. So it is definitely possible to make TBB running on ARM, probably with rather small additional effort. And actually there was [a report about certain success with such a port](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=79566) at the TBB forum.

And, [Intel(R) AppUp SDK for MeeGo](http://appdeveloper.intel.com/en-us/meego-sdk-suite) also [contains TBB](http://appdeveloper.intel.com/en-us/article/using-intel-threading-building-blocks-intel-tbb-library-intel-appuptm-sdk-suite-meego), though it's only for Intel's Atom processor.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not processor dependent.  It is just a C++ library so as long as the compiler you are using is capable of compiling it you should be fine.  From the FAQ of the website you linked to:

> What compilers, operating systems and processors are supported?
>
> The project is dedicated to supporting all compilers, all OSes and all processors as a cornerstone objective of the project. Up to date information on status is available on the web site.

Edit:  Poking around a little more it looks like people are having problems getting it working on ARM processors, but nothing that should be insurmountable.

Comment: I would give this a "yes, but..." - for threading, there is a lot of difference between clean compilation and tailoring/optimization for a particular target platform.  I would not stake my career on this statement of intent, in short.

Comment: Ok so Intel completely focuses TBB development on P4, later and compatible ( by this I think they mean AMD ) hardware.  They don't even focus on getting it to work on their Atom platform so I doubt they care about anything smaller like ARM.

Comment: Atom is an x86 processor, and if it runs a supported OS, TBB should work out-of-the-box there.

Comment: It will work but as Steve Townsend points out further up there is a difference between will work and works well.

Comment: The API is not processor dependent.  The implementation is.  And it is not strictly a matter of having a C++ compiler - TBB 4.2 has no less than 88 references to inline assembly, all of which are, by definition, architecture-specific (which implies processor specificity).